# Preg match {{statement}} expression

Tags: php, regex

I have following regex to match {{statement}}.

```
#{{(.*?)}}#
```

I am using this in preg_replace_callback. It works fine but problem with this is, it breaks if there is another block within same. 
As an example following will break

```
{{$a="{{name}}"}}
```

It matches upto `{{$a="{{name}}`, but i want it match `{{$a="{{name}}"}}`.

If possible i am fine with escape character like this.

```
{{$a="\{{name}}"}}
```

In this case block starts with \ will be escaped.

Comment: Are you looking for a recursive approach? Sth. like [**`\{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+\}`**](https://regex101.com/r/YZfotG/1/) ?

Comment: @jan its working, please add to answer.

Comment: it's working but not correct since this regexp does not assume exact `{{` and matches even `{...}`. Consider this `\{{2}(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+\}{2}`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your input data is, you could maybe state that the pattern should start with the `{{`, and end with  `}}`?

Using the `#^{{(.*?)}}$#` as a pattern [yields the following result](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jWF):

```
{{$a="string"}} --> $a="string"
{{$b="{{complex}}"}} --> $b="{{complex}}"
```

Alright, [switching out the regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jWH) to `^({{(?:.*?)}})$` now yields:

```
{{$a="string"}} --> {{$a="string"}}
{{$b="{{complex}}"}} --> {{$b="{{complex}}}}"
```

Comment: Yes but i want to improve regex here so it matches whole block and ignores block inside another block.

Comment: It fails if expression is side by like this `{{$a="string"}} {{$name}}`

Comment: Please check @jan's comment

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with `{{(.*?)}}` is asking regex to match **lazily**. 
`*?` quantifier matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy search).

You should use `{{(.*)}}`.

`*` is for as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/veQ6CC/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you might be looking for a recursive approach:

```
\{                # match {
(?:[^{}]*|(?R))+  # match not {} or repeat the pattern
\}                # match }
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YZfotG/1/).